# Error in file reading and insert in a set

Tags: c++, set

I am trying to read a file with this format:

```
  4
  0
  0 0 2 a 0 b 1
  1 1 2 a 1 b 2
  2 1 2 a 1 b 3
  3 0 2 a 3 b 3
```

And print in the screen. But the output I get is:

```
  4
  0
  0 0 2 a 0 b 1 
  1 1 2 a 0 b 1 
  2 1 2 a 0 b 1 
  3 0 2 a 0 b 1
```

This is my main:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    #include "estado.hpp"
    #include "DFA.hpp"
    #include "trancisiones.hpp"

    using namespace std;

    int main(void){

    DFA_t dfa;
    dfa.leerdfa();
    dfa.mostrardfa();

    }
```

And I got 3 classes:
DFA.hpp:

```
    #include "estado.hpp"
    #include <set>
    #include <iterator>

    using namespace std;

    class DFA_t {
    private:
       unsigned inicial;
       int nestados;
       set<estado_t> estados;
    public:
       int leerdfa(void);
       void mostrardfa(void);
    };
```

DFA.cpp:

```
    int DFA_t::leerdfa(void){
        estado_t estado;
        estados.clear();
        string ruta;
        cout << "introduzca la ruta del archivo: ";
        cin >> ruta;
        ifstream fichero(ruta.c_str());
        if (fichero.is_open()) {
               fichero >> nestados >> inicial;
               for(int i=0;i<nestados;i++){
                      estado.leerestado(fichero);
                       estados.insert(estado);
               }
        }
        else {
               cout << endl;
               cout << "No se ha podido abrir el fichero." << endl;
        }
        return fichero.is_open();
        fichero.close();
    }

    void DFA_t::mostrardfa(void){
        estado_t estado;
        cout << nestados << endl;
        cout << inicial << endl;
        for (set<estado_t>::iterator i = estados.begin(); i != estados.end(); i++){
             estado = *i;
             estado.mostrarestado();
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
```

estado.hpp:

```
               #pragma once

               #include <iostream>
               #include <set>
               #include <fstream>

               #include "transiciones.hpp"

               using namespace std;

               class estado_t {
               private:
               unsigned aceptacion;
               int ntransiciones;
               unsigned identificador;
               set<transicion_t> transiciones;

               public:
               void leerestado(ifstream& fichero_);
               void mostrarestado(void);


               int operator==(const estado_t &estado_) const;
               int operator<(const estado_t &estado_) const;
               estado_t &operator=(const estado_t &estado_);
               };
```

estado.cpp:

```
           #include "estado.hpp"

           void estado_t::leerestado(ifstream& fichero_){
                 transicion_t tran;
                 fichero_ >> identificador >> aceptacion >> ntransiciones;
                 for (int i=0;i<ntransiciones;i++){
                 tran.leer_transicion(fichero_);
                 transiciones.insert(tran);
               }
            }

           void estado_t::mostrarestado(void){
              transicion_t transicion;
              cout << identificador << " " << aceptacion << " " << ntransiciones << "        ";
              for (set<transicion_t>::iterator i = transiciones.begin(); i !=           transiciones.end(); i++){
                  transicion = *i; 
                  cout << transicion.get_elemento() << " " << transicion.get_siguiente()                                  << " ";
                  }
              cout << endl;
              }

              int estado_t::operator==(const estado_t &estado_) const {
              if (this->identificador == estado_.identificador) return 1;
              return 0;
          }

          int estado_t::operator<(const estado_t &estado_) const {
              if (this->identificador < estado_.identificador) return 1;
              return 0;
          } 

          estado_t& estado_t::operator=(const estado_t &estado_) {
              this->aceptacion = estado_.aceptacion;
              this->ntransiciones = estado_.ntransiciones;
              this->identificador = estado_.identificador;
              this->transiciones = estado_.transiciones;
              return *this;
          }
```

transiciones.hpp

```
          #include <iostream>
          #include <fstream>
          using namespace std;

           class transicion_t {
                private:
                    char elemento;
                    unsigned siguiente;
                public:
                    char get_elemento(void);
                    unsigned get_siguiente(void);

                    void leer_transicion(ifstream& fichero_);
                    void mostrar_transicion(void);

                    int operator==(const transicion_t &transicion_) const;
                    int operator<(const transicion_t &transicion_) const;
                    transicion_t &operator=(const transicion_t &transicion_);
               };
```

transiciones.cpp:

```
                   #include "transiciones.hpp"

                   char transicion_t::get_elemento(void){
                       return elemento;
                   }

                   unsigned transicion_t::get_siguiente(void){
                       return siguiente;
                   }

                   void transicion_t::leer_transicion(ifstream& fichero_) {
                        fichero_ >> elemento >> siguiente; 
                   }

                   int transicion_t::operator==(const transicion_t &transicion_) const {
                   if ((this->elemento == transicion_.elemento)&&(this->siguiente == transicion_.siguiente)) return 1;
                   return 0;
                   }

                   int transicion_t::operator<(const transicion_t &transicion_) const {
                      if (this->elemento < transicion_.elemento) return 1;
                      return 0;
                   }

                   transicion_t& transicion_t::operator=(const transicion_t &transicion_) {
                       this->elemento = transicion_.elemento;
                       this->siguiente = transicion_.siguiente;
                       return *this;
                   }
```

It's for a DFA implementation. Everything else in the implementation works.

Comment: std::set is an ordered data structure. When you place data in it, it gets sorted. If you need to preserve the ordering, you will have to select a different container. What are the requirements of the container?

Comment: please try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You should try to debug this yourself, e.g. check the size of the set after every call to `transiciones.insert(tran)`. (Also, [you are not checking the result of any read operations](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check))